# How to add one day to a blocked date?

Tags: javascript, html

## Hello

I'm creating a flight ticket booking app on which user will choose from when to when he would to book a flight. Right now I'm troubleshooting with the input data because I departure day I want to disable option of choosing an earlier day than booking day and also I want to disable an option of choosing a return day same as departure day or earlier. I have found a soultion of first part of this project but I don't know how to do the second part. I've that maybay I could add the same condition as in the departure day + one day.
Below I insert the code which I've created.

Html

```
` <label for="departureDate"></label>
        <p>Departure date</p>
        <input type="date" name="departureDate" id="departureDate">

    <label for="arrivalDate"></label>
        <p>Arrival date</p>
        <input type="date" name="arrivalDate" id="arrivalDate">
    `
```

Js

```
`const departureDate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]
const inputDepartureDate = document.querySelector('#departureDate')
console.log(inputDepartureDate)
inputDepartureDate.setAttribute('min', departureDate)
console.log(departureDate)

document.getElementById('arrivalDate').addEventListener('change', () => {
    const arrivalDate = departureDate + 1
    console.log(arrivalDate)
    console.log(arrivalDate.setDate(departureDate.getDate() + 1))

    const inputArrivalDate = document.querySelector('#arrivalDate')
    inputArrivalDate.setAttribute('min', arrivalDate)
    console.log(arrivalDate)
})
`
```

I header that `moment.js` pack can help me with this problem but does somebody know how to do without it?
[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

I searched the Internet and tried to use chatgpt to find a solution and I didn't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

With help of the user who deleted his comment I've figured out how to do this.
Below I put the code to JavaScript - Html stays the same

JS

```
    Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  const date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;

}

const departureDate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]
const inputDepartureDate = document.querySelector('#departureDate')
inputDepartureDate.setAttribute('min', departureDate)

const inputArrivalDate = document.querySelector('#arrivalDate')
inputArrivalDate.setAttribute('min', new Date(departureDate).addDays(1).toISOString().split('T')[0])

inputDepartureDate.addEventListener('change', () => {
    inputArrivalDate.setAttribute('min', new Date(inputDepartureDate.value).addDays(1).toISOString().split('T')[0])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).